# android launch modes

Tags: android

In my android application i am using standard launch mode for all activities.In my application i have a footer bar with home icon to navigate to homescreen from any application activity.the home screen is getting created that many times.If i place the launch mode as single instance the same activity is popped up but even if the data i am expecting is different it is popping up the same data with initial data.

Please let me know as how can i get new activity created only if there is change of data.

Please forward me your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

[`singleInstance`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) mode means that first time, when activity is created, `onCreate()` will be called. However on subsequent invocations `onNewIntent()` is called instead.

So you should override `onNewIntent()` and reload the data and update the display there.

Comment: Ohh ok.Thanks Peter for quick reply.Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

This way, the onCreate of your HomeActivity will run again.